# Multiplying a range in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have store weight in lbs in my column which I need to convert to KG. I was able to do it with a simple query:

```
SELECT ( weight * 0.45 ) as weight from TABLE
```

However, this doesn't work values which are stored as a range, ex. '200 - 300'. If I use the same query it returns `440.925` instead of `440-661`. I understand this is happening because I'm multiplying string but is there a way I can multiple a range value (200-300) to get the desired result.

If not, how should I convert this range ideally?

Comment: You really should consider converting the data

Comment: I know I don't like it too, but it's a design decision that was made way earlier and I cannot change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) is useful here:

```
SELECT IF(
  INSTR(weight, '-') > 0, /* Does weight contain a dash? */
  CONCAT( /* Yes? Multiply each, and return them: */
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(weight, '-', 1) * 0.45,
      ' - ',
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(weight, '-', -1) * 0.45
  ),
  weight * 0.45 /* No? Just simply multiply the weight */
) AS `range`
FROM test
```

First, we check to see if weight contains a dash, and if it does, split it up, and multiply them out individually.

See an example here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iELvWDjpVGBZEkpdR4jtsK/0

Answer (score 0):

Using [CAST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast), and [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) functions.

1. `CAST` will ensure that even if there are more spaces on either side of the **'-'** (hyphen) character, it will still convert it into a valid number. You can change the `DECIMAL(10,4)` to any precision, as per your application requirements.
2. `SUBSTRING_INDEX` will find the substring before the occurence of '-' (hyphen) character.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(weight, '-', 1) AS DECIMAL(10,4)) * 0.45,
         '-', 
         CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(weight, '-', -1) AS DECIMAL(10,4)) * 0.45) 
  AS weight 
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly you need to do something like below.

```
SELECT
 CONCAT (
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, ' - ', 1), ' - ', -1) * 0.45
   , ' - '
   , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, ' - ', 2), ' - ', -1) * 0.45
 )
FROM
 table
```

1) Nesting `SUBSTRING_INDEX` functions makes it possible to extract items from a string. 
2) CAST function is not needed because of MySQL autotype cast.